# If $F\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ then $F\subset U_n$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $U_n$ be open sets in $\Bbb R^d$ such that $U_{n}\subset U_{n+1}$ for $n\geq 1$. If $F\subset\Bbb R^d$ is a closed set such that $F\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$, then $F\subset U_n$ for some large $n$?

If the ambient space is compact, $\Bbb S^d$ for example, then the statement is clear. But I wonder if this is true for non-compact ambient space.

Comment: $U_n = (-n, n), F = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Well, I won't delete the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $U_n=B_n(0)$ and $F=\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Thanks. I was too lazy.